# Maximizing Partial Likelihood using R code

Tags: r, survival-analysis

Suppose I have a lifetime data set like kidney data. There are some covariates age, sex, disease. Sex have 2 categories (F,M) and disease have 4 categories (Other, GN, AN, PKD). I want to estimate the parameters of Cox proportional hazard model. There are 5 parameters for age, sex, GN, AN, PKD. I am trying like this. How can I maximize this function?

```
library(survival)
dat <- kidney
head(kidney)
#      id time status age sex disease frail
#    1  1    8      1  28   1   Other   2.3
#    2  1   16      1  28   1   Other   2.3
#    3  2   23      1  48   2      GN   1.9
#    4  2   13      0  48   2      GN   1.9
#    5  3   22      1  32   1   Other   1.2
#    6  3   28      1  32   1   Other   1.2  
    ......................................
```

## Partial likelihood function

```
logPL <- function( par, time, status, cov ){
  data <- data.frame( time, status, cov)
  data <- data[order(data$time, decreasing=T),]
  risk.score <- data.matrix(data[,-c(1:2)]) %*% par
  PL1 <- risk.set
  PL2 <- log(cumsum(exp(risk.set)))
  PL <- sum(data$status*(PL1-PL2))
  return(-PL)}
```

Comment: it seems that your partial likelihood is wrong...

Comment: I think `coxph(Surv(time, status)~ age + sex + disease, kidney)` is all what you need. Why do you need to write your own partial likelihood function?

Comment: I think my partial likelihood is right. Yes coxph code of survival package works. But I want to understand how it works and how can I write a function if I need. Can you tell me details about its working mechanism? @Randy Lai